# Cannot launch AVD emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

So I was planning on getting back into coding after a little time off. I downloaded Android Studio on my new laptop and created a google maps activity.

The only change I made to the code was insert my api key for google maps. When I tried to launch my app in the emulator, I recieved this:

```
Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
Output:
Creating filesystem with parameters:
ERROR: resizing partition e2fsck failed with exit code 1
    Size: 69206016
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 4224
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 1024
    Label: 
    Blocks: 16896
    Block groups: 1
    Reserved block group size: 7
Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks
Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x60000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5554
emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5554
[3900]:WARNING:./android/base/files/IniFile.cpp:158:Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\Mike Jones\.android\emu-update-last-check.ini for reading.
[17164]:WARNING:./android/base/files/IniFile.cpp:158:Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\Mike Jones\.android\emu-update-last-check.ini for reading.
```

Answer (score 0):

i am using ubuntu 16 64-bit version. in android-studio 2.2 i set my ANDROID_HOME path that was all, no more errors. setting the path looks like:

## open .bashrc file

```
`sudo gedit ~/.bashrc`
```

## then do:

```
`export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk`
`export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools`
```

Comment: This does not solve the issue being asked in the question. You would not be able to compile if ANDROID_HOME was not set

Answer (score -1):

You hae to Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator(HAXM installer) in android sdk
if not done, you play {ANDROID_SDK_HOME}\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Excecution_Manager\intelhaxm-android.exe through admin's permission